# The enter key is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

all i want is to disable the special characters like < > & but the enter key is not working and here's my code

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDetails" Width="660px" CssClass="txtDetails"  TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" Height="170px" onkeypress="return IsAlphaNumeric(event);" />
                 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">Special Characters like < > and & are not allowed.</span>
                <script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
    specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
    specialKeys.push(36); //Home
    specialKeys.push(35); //End
    specialKeys.push(37); //Left
    specialKeys.push(39); //Right
    specialKeys.push(13); //Enter
    function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 1 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode == 13) || (keyCode > 31 && keyCode < 127) && keyCode != 38 && keyCode != 60 && keyCode != 62);
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

this code works to disable the special characters < > & but the ENTER key is not working.
Can anyone help me with my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `specialKeys`, but not using it.

Your `IsAlphaNumeric` function defines `ret`, of which `keyCode == 13` is one of them, so the return value is `true`.

Comment: thanks for the info i forgot to add the && specialKeys on the onkeypress.

Comment: @RobertJohnSustraido if this reply solves your question, click the gray tick at the left side to mark it as the accepted answer.